# "x questions with new activity" usability

Tags: discussion, usability, live-refresh, performance

My installation of Firefox seems to be suffering in the bog of "got too many extensions" senility and isn't as responsive as in its younger years...

However, this has highlighted a usability issue that is causing me to click through to unwanted pages.

When the "x questions with new activity" bar appears at the top of the question list, I click it... nothing happens... did I click it or not? I click it again... it fades away and my second click falls on the link that occupies the position the bar used to occupy. Now I've clicked through to a page that I probably didn't want to visit. I'm very mildly annoyed, as I've done this 4-5 times today.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with a UserScript, AddOn or something similar. Like the first event doesn't fire or the page does not refresh after the event.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Note on spelling of usability/useability: both forms are correct, hence you correction is unwarranted. http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/usable?q=useability#usable__2

Comment: @user133351 Huh, neat. Learned something new today, I guess. Thanks. :)

Comment: My issue with this UI design is making clickable stuff appear directly underneath something that disappears on click isn't all that good, regardless of my occasionally chuggy browser.

Comment: Ha! I'd swear someone figured out that there was a problem with this feature... The Javascript avalanche caused by clicking the bar no longer occurs. Much better.